# Eclipse CDT formatter lines up columns with macros incorrectly?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, eclipse-cdt

##### Background

Using STM32CubeMxIDE 1.8 (Eclipse® 2021-03 and CDTTM version 10.2.0). I've adjusted to a custom formatter with `Window` >> `Preferences` >> `C/C++` >> `CodeStyle` >> `Formatter` >> `Edit`, and created my own with some Google, GNU, and personal preference. I want something like this for large functions:

```
foo(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000);
```

##### Issue

Given my poorly formatted code:

```
#define mainEXAMPLE_32BIT  0x00000000

__myExampleFunctionFoo (  mainEXAMPLE_32BIT, mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,    mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,mainEXAMPLE_32BIT);
```

If I format by save or pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and format the entire page it becomes:

```
__myExampleFunctionFoo(mainEXAMPLE_32BIT, mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,
                       mainEXAMPLE_32BIT, mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,
                       mainEXAMPLE_32BIT);
```

Great! This is what I want.

But it only works once. When I save file or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> a second time and I now have:

```
__myExampleFunctionFoo(mainEXAMPLE_32BIT, mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,
mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,
                       mainEXAMPLE_32BIT,
                       mainEXAMPLE_32BIT);
```

The second argument moves forward to the same indentation as it's function. This only seems to happen with defines/macros.

I've tried my own, GNU, and other CDT formatters options. I suspect if it's not a bug that it's an issue with expansion of macros or generally some macro option.

Any advice? I suspect the best response I'll get is to install Clang-Format.

Comment: You are using an older version of CDT, and a **very** old version of Eclipse. Try updating both, and if the problem persists, filing a bug report.

Comment: I updated it. I quickly click ABOUT and thought it said 4.2, but the documentation says Eclipse® 2021-03 and CDTTM version 10.2.0 so I probably read the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find nothing on this, no way to see what the built in formatter was doing and why, and did eventually switch to clang-format.

The plug-in for Eclipse is called CppStyle.